# UIAlertController handler becomes nil

Tags: objective-c-blocks, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I have an `UIAlertController` in my app, so i want show alert everytime `menuButton` pressed. I need to recreate `_menuAlert` for specific idea (It need to check object for another `action`,that are not described). So if i keep `_shareAction`, but recreate `UIAlertController`, somehow, it's handler becomes `nil`.

I feel missing something big about blocks to understand why this happens. Please, help me understand.

There is code:

```
- (UIAlertController *)menuAlert
{
    _menuAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                     message:nil
                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    @weakify(self);
    if (!_shareAction)
    {
        _shareAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"SHARE_BTN_TEXT", nil)
                                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
                                                  @strongify(self);
                                                  [self.navigationController presentShareVCWithList:_list];
                                              }];
    }

    if (!_cancelAction) {
        _cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ALERT_CANCEL", nil)
                                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                               handler:nil];
    }


    [_menuAlert addAction:_shareAction];
    [_menuAlert addAction:_cancelAction];

    return _menuAlert;
}
```

How menuAlert called :

```
- (void)menuButtonPressed 
{
    [self presentViewController:self.menuAlert animated:YES completion:nil];
    self.menuAlert.view.tintColor = COLOR_BACKGROUND_GREEN;
}
```